# command line alternative to dpkg-reconfigure slapd

Tags: linux, openldap, dpkg, slapd

Is there a way to reconfigure slapd, providing all configuration options as command-line parameters/arguments?
My goal is to be find an alternative to the interactive UI.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive slapd`